# iconitemrenderer clickable objects?

Tags: android, apache-flex, mxml, itemrenderer, navigator

I am making a mobile application in Flash Builder 4.5 for android and iOS and am using the itemRenderer and iconitemrenderer classes to make a list of options for my app. For some reason, i cannot make them clickable, or define actions to do when each is clicked. Basically, i'm aiming to use FB's "views", and when an item is clicked, to switch to a new view. Here's the code i'm working with:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:ms="libs/MessageBox-digitalRetro">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button id="signin" label="Sign in" click="onSignIn(event)"/>
    </s:actionContent>
        //code for the clicking of the sign in button
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function onSignIn(event:Event):void
            {

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:List height="100%" width="100%">
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:IconItemRenderer height="100" labelField="name" 
                                    iconField="photo" iconHeight="80" 
                                    iconWidth="80" messageFunction="getMessage">
                    <fx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            import spark.components.NavigatorContent;
                                                    //this first method works
                            protected function getMessage(o:Object):String
                            {
                                return o.message;
                            }
                        ]]>
                    </fx:Script>
                </s:IconItemRenderer>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayCollection>
                <fx:Object name="Projects" photo="@Embed('libs/ProjectsIcon2.png')" message="Learn more about what we're working on" clickfn="views/Projects"/>
                <fx:Object name="Locate Office" photo="@Embed('libs/google-maps-icon.png')" message="Find directions to our nearest office" clickfn=""/>
                <fx:Object name="Contact Us" photo="@Embed('libs/gmailicon.png')" message="Let us know your thoughts!" clickfn=""/>
                <fx:Object name="About Us" photo="@Embed('libs/info-icon.png')" message="" clickfn=""/>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:dataProvider>
            <s:change>
        <![CDATA[
                // NEW!!!
            var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.clickfn) as Class;
            navigator.pushView(ClassReference);
        ]]>
    </s:change>
    </s:List>
</s:View>
```

EDIT: i added the "change" tag, and it compiles now, but i get an error message:

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Projects is not defined.
    at global/flash.utils::getDefinitionByName()
    at views::MainHomeView/___MainHomeView_List1_change()[C:\Users\jlehenbauer\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\Metters Inc\src\views\MainHomeView.mxml:56]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13128]
    at spark.components::List/commitSelection()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\List.as:1205]
    at spark.components.supportClasses::ListBase/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\ListBase.as:939]
    at spark.components::List/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\List.as:1069]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8209]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:597]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:813]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]

Comment: +1 for almost providing runnable code.  The embedded images make it slightly hard to copy and paste run; but this is better than most.

Comment: thanks! and it should run without the images, you'll just get an error message and have to tell it to `Proceed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the change handler logic in JacobL's answer by doing something like this:

```
<s:List id="list1" height="100%" width="100%" change="navigator.pushView(list1.selectedItem.nextView)">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:IconItemRenderer labelField="name"/>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:DataItem name="Projects" message="Learn more about what we're working on" nextView="{views.Projects}" />
            <s:DataItem name="Locate Office" message="Find directions to our nearest office" nextView="{views.Locate}" />
            <s:DataItem name="Contact Us" message="Let us know your thoughts!" nextView="{views.ContactUs}" />
            <s:DataItem name="About Us" message="" nextView="{views.AboutUs}" />
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am making a mobile application in
>   Flash Builder 4.5 for android and iOS
>   and am using the itemRenderer and
>   iconitemrenderer classes to make a
>   list of options for my app.

Actually,based on the code you've shown in your example you are not using the [ItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ItemRenderer.html) class; just the [IconItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/IconItemRenderer.html) class.  The syntax you see, like this:

is a syntax used to define properties of the component as children in MXML.  It refers to the itemRenderer property of the List component; it does not refer tot he ItemRenderer class.

That said, the error appears to be that you are trying to reference a string `clickfn="Projects"`as if it were a class.  Therefore you get a type conversion error.  If you specify the full class path, you may have better luck.

Also, three of your items have no clickFn defined; so they will probably throw similar errors.

Comment: IconItemRenderer is within the ItemRenderer class, so i'm using them both. But, i see what you're saying about the error. i hadn't defined it for the others yet, as i was just testing, and i tried your advice, but the code still did not work. i've edited the code to show the changes

Comment: i tried the code above as well as the full path `Package/src/views/Projects` and it still was not functional

Comment: No; IconItemRenderer is not within the ItemRenderer class.  At least not in the code you provided to us.  I think I already explaned that; but I'm not sure how to make it more clear.  Generally if it starts with a lower case 'itemRenderer' it is a property.  If it starts with upper case "ItemRenderer" it is a class.  You are just using MXML syntax to assign an instance of the IconItemRenderer class to the itemRenderer property of the list.

Comment: I believe you need to access the package structure; not the directory structure.  So, use dot notation.   'views.Projects' not 'views/Projects'

Comment: @Flextras i changed the `<s:change>` code to a function that is supposed to change the reference to an instance of the class with that name, but it seems to think it is simply a variable and not a class. any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you changed.  But, you may have issues w/ how you create the dataProvider.  I've never tried to create class variables like that on a generic object in MXML.  Try to revert to ActionScript creation of your dataProvider.  Something strikes me as "wrong" w/ the code; but without something I can run and step through I'm not sure what.  But, wouldn't the pushView need an instance of the class; not the actual class?

Comment: @JacobL let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/970/discussion-between-www-flextras-com-and-jacobl)

Comment: I'm not sure what that chat thing is; it's new.

Answer (score 1):

You can get ride of the conditionals by doing the suggestion above like so:

```
<pre>
<s:dataProvider>
<s:ArrayList>
    <s:DataItem name="Projects" message="Learn more about what we're working on"   nextView="{views.Projects}" />
    <s:DataItem name="Locate Office" message="Find directions to our nearest office" nextView="{views.Locate}" />
    <s:DataItem name="Contact Us" message="Let us know your thoughts!" nextView="{views.ContactUs}" />
    <s:DataItem name="About Us" message="" nextView="{views.AboutUs}" />
    </s:ArrayList></s:dataProvider>

<s:change>
navigator.pushView(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.nextView);
</s:change>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. here's a solution:

```
<s:List height="100%" width="100%">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:IconItemRenderer height="100" labelField="name" 
                                iconField="photo" iconHeight="80" 
                                iconWidth="80" messageFunction="getMessage">
                <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        import spark.components.NavigatorContent;
                        protected function getMessage(o:Object):String
                        {
                            return o.message;
                        }
                    ]]>
                </fx:Script>
            </s:IconItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayCollection>
            <fx:Object name="Projects" photo="@Embed('libs/ProjectsIcon2.png')" message="Learn more about what we're working on">
            </fx:Object>
            <fx:Object name="Locate Office" photo="@Embed('libs/google-maps-icon.png')" message="Find directions to our nearest office">
            </fx:Object>
            <fx:Object name="Contact Us" photo="@Embed('libs/gmailicon.png')" message="Let us know your thoughts!">
            </fx:Object>
            <fx:Object name="About Us" photo="@Embed('libs/info-icon.png')" message="">
            </fx:Object>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:dataProvider>
    <s:change>
              //these if statements were the solution i used. rough, but works well
        <![CDATA[
            if(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.name == "Projects"){navigator.pushView(Projects);}
        if(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.name == "Locate Office"){navigator.pushView(Locations);}
        if(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.name == "Contact Us"){navigator.pushView(Contact);}
        if(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.name == "About Us"){navigator.pushView(About);}
        ]]>
    </s:change>
</s:List>
```